# Как убрать первую вертикальную линию в графике?

Tags: javascript, диаграммы

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой, имеется линейный график на amCharts, есть потребность убрать первую и последнюю вертикальные линии на графике. Возможно кто-то сталкивался или имеет представление как, буду благодарен за помощь.

[image: Пример что именно нужно спрятать]

```js
    am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
        am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart
        var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
        chart.padding(0, 15, 0, 15);
        var colorSale = "#75af26";
        var colorBuy = "#269cb5";
// Load external data
        var data = [];
        var price1 = 1000;
        var price2 = 2000;
        var price3 = 3000;
        var quantity = 1000;
        for (var i = 15; i < 3000; i++) {
            price1 += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 100);
            price2 += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 100);

            if (price1 < 100) {
                price1 = 100;
            }

            if (price2 < 100) {
                price2 = 100;
            }


            quantity += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 500);

            if (quantity < 0) {
                quantity *= -1;
            }
            data.push({ date: new Date(2000, 0, i), price1: price1, price2:price2, quantity: quantity });
        }


        chart.data = data;

// the following line makes value axes to be arranged vertically.
        chart.leftAxesContainer.layout = "vertical";
        
        var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
        dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
        dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.length = 8;
        dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 0.2;
        dateAxis.renderer.minLabelPosition = 0.01;
        dateAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.99;
        dateAxis.keepSelection = true;
        dateAxis.renderer.fontSize = "13px";
        dateAxis.minHeight = 30;


        dateAxis.groupData = true;
        dateAxis.maxZoomLevel = 1;


        var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
        valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
        valueAxis.zIndex = 1;
        valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
// height of axis
        valueAxis.height = am4core.percent(65);

        valueAxis.renderer.gridContainer.background.fillOpacity = 0.05;
        valueAxis.renderer.inside = true;
        valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "bottom";
        valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.padding(2, 2, 2, 2);

//valueAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.95;
        valueAxis.renderer.fontSize = "13px"

        var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
        series.dataFields.valueY = "price1";
        series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
        series.name = "MSFT: Value";
        series.strokeWidth = 3;
        series.stroke = am4core.color(colorSale);
        series.tensionX = 0.77;
        series.defaultState.transitionDuration = 0;



// volume should be summed
        var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series2.dataFields.dateX = "date";
        series2.dataFields.valueY = "price2";
        series2.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
        series2.name = "MSFT: Value";
        series2.strokeWidth = 3;
        series2.stroke = am4core.color(colorBuy);
        series2.tensionX = 0.77;
        series2.defaultState.transitionDuration = 0;

        chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

        var scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
        scrollbarX.series.push(series);
        scrollbarX.marginBottom = 20;
        scrollbarX.scrollbarChart.xAxes.getIndex(0).minHeight = undefined;
        chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;

        var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
        var bullet2 = series2.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
        bullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
        bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
        bullet.fillOpacity = 0;
        bullet.strokeOpacity = 0;
        bullet2.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
        bullet2.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
        bullet2.fillOpacity = 0;
        bullet2.strokeOpacity = 0;

        var bulletState = bullet.states.create("hover");
        bulletState.properties.fillOpacity = 1;
        bulletState.properties.strokeOpacity = 1;
        var bulletState2 = bullet2.states.create("hover");
        bulletState2.properties.fillOpacity = 1;
        bulletState2.properties.strokeOpacity = 1;


        // Make a panning cursor
        chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
        chart.cursor.behavior = "none";
        

    });
```

```css
#chartdiv{
   width: 100%;
   height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<article class="block-content block-chart">
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="wr_inner">
            <div id="chartdiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/hmBjb4r наверно у нас заблочено это

Comment: Я про горизонтальные говорил, а здесь про первую вертикальную. На графике года отделены вертикальными линиями, и справедливо, что раз начало графика совпадает с началом года имеется и вертикальная вначале. Попробуйте сместить начало на 1 день)

Comment: `data.push({ date: new Date(2000, 1, i), price1: price1, price2:price2, quantity: quantity });` Вот так получилось, с февраля если

Comment: Ну смотрите, вы просто по сути зарезали один месяц январь, я не мел ввиду что-то делать с датами и значениями, а только убрать саму первую и последнюю вертикальные линии.

У кого не выполняется код, можно тут(https://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-different-colors-ups-downs/) глянуть,там есть ссылка на codepen

Comment: @DpaceSpace а amcharts.com....ваще internal error -наверно заблокированный сайт у нас

Comment: Wow, сорян. Хз что это.
https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true
А если так?

Comment: я имел ввиду то что всё что с amcharts хоть scripts хоть что то ещё не пашет у меня

Comment: Adblock может?)

Comment: Удивительные люди, пользуетесь готовыми решениями, но надо именно с "перламутровыми" пуговицами. Копайте исходный код библиотек, исправляйте под себя. Нет? Сами напишите как вам надо.

Comment: "Удивительный человек" написал ответ, который не совпал и сразу "да вообще напишите сами библиотеку....". Если нету что по сути вопроса ответить, проходим мимо

Comment: `dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 1;` // ДАННЫЕ ПОСТРАДАЛИ?

Comment: @DpaceSpace https://ibb.co/Rb0jkfX он выключен когда я на so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = -0.001;`

Смещается отображение сетки немного влево, на данные не влияет.

`dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 2;`

Можно и так, в общем, можете поиграть этим параметром и получить желаемый результат.

```js
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart
    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
    chart.padding(0, 15, 0, 15);
    var colorSale = "#75af26";
    var colorBuy = "#269cb5";
// Load external data
    var data = [];
    var price1 = 1000;
    var price2 = 2000;
    var price3 = 3000;
    var quantity = 1000;
    for (var i = 15; i < 3000; i++) {
        price1 += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 100);
        price2 += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 100);

        if (price1 < 100) {
            price1 = 100;
        }

        if (price2 < 100) {
            price2 = 100;
        }


        quantity += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 500);

        if (quantity < 0) {
            quantity *= -1;
        }
        data.push({ date: new Date(2000, 0, i), price1: price1, price2:price2, quantity: quantity });
    }


    chart.data = data;

// the following line makes value axes to be arranged vertically.
    chart.leftAxesContainer.layout = "vertical";
    
    var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = -0.001;  // ЗДЕСЬ ЭТО!!!!
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.length = 8;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 0.2;
    dateAxis.renderer.minLabelPosition = 0.01;
    dateAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.99;
    dateAxis.keepSelection = true;
    dateAxis.renderer.fontSize = "13px";
    dateAxis.minHeight = 30;


    dateAxis.groupData = true;
    dateAxis.maxZoomLevel = 1;


    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
    valueAxis.zIndex = 1;
    valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
// height of axis
    valueAxis.height = am4core.percent(65);

    valueAxis.renderer.gridContainer.background.fillOpacity = 0.05;
    valueAxis.renderer.inside = true;
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "bottom";
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.padding(2, 2, 2, 2);

//valueAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.95;
    valueAxis.renderer.fontSize = "13px"

    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
    series.dataFields.valueY = "price1";
    series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
    series.name = "MSFT: Value";
    series.strokeWidth = 3;
    series.stroke = am4core.color(colorSale);
    series.tensionX = 0.77;
    series.defaultState.transitionDuration = 0;



// volume should be summed
    var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    series2.dataFields.dateX = "date";
    series2.dataFields.valueY = "price2";
    series2.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
    series2.name = "MSFT: Value";
    series2.strokeWidth = 3;
    series2.stroke = am4core.color(colorBuy);
    series2.tensionX = 0.77;
    series2.defaultState.transitionDuration = 0;

    chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

    var scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
    scrollbarX.series.push(series);
    scrollbarX.marginBottom = 20;
    scrollbarX.scrollbarChart.xAxes.getIndex(0).minHeight = undefined;
    chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;

    var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
    var bullet2 = series2.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
    bullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
    bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
    bullet.fillOpacity = 0;
    bullet.strokeOpacity = 0;
    bullet2.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
    bullet2.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
    bullet2.fillOpacity = 0;
    bullet2.strokeOpacity = 0;

    var bulletState = bullet.states.create("hover");
    bulletState.properties.fillOpacity = 1;
    bulletState.properties.strokeOpacity = 1;
    var bulletState2 = bullet2.states.create("hover");
    bulletState2.properties.fillOpacity = 1;
    bulletState2.properties.strokeOpacity = 1;


    // Make a panning cursor
    chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
    chart.cursor.behavior = "none";
    

});
```

```css
#chartdiv{
   width: 100%;
   height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<article class="block-content block-chart">
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="wr_inner">
        <div id="chartdiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</article>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это именно оно!

Comment: Последнюю вряд ли убрать так просто можно без разбора кода, там просто как шаг попадет.

Comment: Я дальше разберусь, еще раз спасибо. Нужно английский подтягивать, без него тяжело документацию читать

Comment: Было б на пользу. Не за что.

Comment: Мне даже больше 1 нужно было убрать, с последней уже не сильно важно